# How to implement LogoutFilter?

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

Hi guys I am building a Java web app using JSF. For authentication I have used Apache Shiro.I have built a logout button which is calling the logout method of shiro and then I redirect the user to login page. But If I click back button the user can navigate into pages. I read about this and I realized that I had to implement my own custom filter. This is the code of the filter :

```
import al.ikubinfo.ipermit.bpmn.model.entities.UserEntity;
import al.ikubinfo.ipermit.bpmn.services.UserService;

public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "/login.xhtml";

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        UserEntity currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest.getServletContext().getContextPath() + LOGIN_VIEW);
        }

        else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I have also included it in the web.xml but it doesnt work. The application start successfully but noe view is opened. Can someone help me please?

Comment: That won't help. When using the back button you are seeing a cached version of the page. The page is cached locally in the browser. To disable that create a filter that includes headers that disables caching for pages.

Comment: I added them but still the login page is not opened

Comment: Your UserService gives back a none `nil` value. If you store the currentUser there in a variable, then set it to nil. And if you do a logout, call an invalidate on the session object as well.

Answer (score 0):

When using the back button you are seeing a cached version of the page. The page is cached locally in the browser.

After logout you must be going to login page

Use following javascript on this page

```
var url = window.location.href;
window.history.go(-window.history.length);
window.location.href = url;
```

Also try to insert

```
<META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

into jsp pages so that browser dont cache the pages.